# How to plot events on time

Tags: charts

Let say that I have this data:

```
        A    B
10 ->   1
30 ->        1
40 ->   0
70 ->   1
80 ->        0
```

I want to plot the states of A and B through time (0->100):
In text, this will give me something like :

```
A -> [10, 40[, [70, 100[
B -> [30, 80[
```

Those graphs there are quite good : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772421/how-to-plot-events-on-time-on-using-matplotlib but in my case, the step is not constant (in real, they are timestamped events).

[UPDATE] Something like this:
[image: mockup]

How can it be done (no matter if it's in Excel or in matplotlib or something else) ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to get the output that you show (the one with all the left square brackets)? Or do you want an actual chart; something like the ones in the answers to the question you linked to?  Can you show us a mock-up of what you want?

Comment: I updated my question as requested

Comment: In what form do you have the data? Maybe https://plantuml.com/en/timing-diagram example: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/JOyn3iCW34NtVmeh2sD0YPICm4rems2feH7GeRUlrRXLjlS_3rlshQVQN_i3Dowflca80wL6uP_ZDqV0KESzqxDoBZrlW7SMWRYH4vuiuezdxQtmSd5MSRGtTCXUllEHIh_C70ryWBFdbzcU-g8PFc9INlNDZF2vR7B21m00 (Use the `View as PNG` or `View as SVG` links to see the generated image.)

Comment: @Bodo Let's say it's a text files with timestamp of the transition and the new status (ON or OFF). One text file for A and one text file for B.

Comment: @Jona Your wording "Let's say it's a text file..." gets me to the impression that your real input format is different. But anyway, you should [edit] your question and add this information there. Showing an actual example with explanation would be better than a vague textual description. Another PlantUML example as close as I can get it: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/LT0nImGn40NWVdx5uvghF1G5jSjkP-yV69CvCvmtEPAHKsJ_ks65bS0qxtt5WmdDkVhd-ODYiQXDi9jsu8RflvZNOYRQuyBLDUg5pL6gYhaaeZ3HBRJX9sjAOWlT_SMRXHv6UDo0maoZtM_sD4BVVSszwCV874_mWYH7DO5dGMLx5vJZ6bpF0lxITi0BKh6zusJb2iQRk4l5bRyFz3mk1B7KV_0B

Comment: The data comes from a XML file but I can convert it easily to a text file. That is not where the problem lies. The PlantUML example is satisfying. Thanks !